# Ubuntu Budgie - Bluetooth Keyboard Anker A7721 Won't Work

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple, budgie, dvorak

I have an Anker A7721 keyboard possibly with a Simplified Dvorak Layout (No Numpad on the right) that looks like this Apple Keyboard:
[Apple Dvorak Simplified Keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard#/media/File:2010_Apple_Wireless_Keyboard_arranged_in_Dvorak_Layout.png)

The problem is only some keys on the top right work like jkl & 789. This problem also affects Apple Keyboard with this specific layout. I've read that using Fn+F6 turns of numlock, but that hasn't worked on my computer. I also can't find:

"To disable numlock by default, go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Layout Options -> Miscellaneous compatibility options -> turn on "Default numeric keypad keys"

Before 17.04, my bluetooth Microsoft Designer Mouse didn't work, so it's finally good to see the problem fixed. I'm using Ubuntu Budgie 17.04.